# Long ints in Fortran

Tags: loops, fortran, largenumber

I'm trying to work with large numbers (~10^14), and I need to be able to store them and iterate over loops of that length, i.e.

```
n=SOME_BIG_NUMBER
do i=n,1,-1
```

I've tried the usual star notation, `kind=8` etc. but nothing seems to work. 
Then I checked the `huge` intrinsic function, and the code:

```
program inttest

print *,huge(1)
print *,huge(2)
print *,huge(4)
print *,huge(8)
print *,huge(16)
print *,huge(32)

end program inttest
```

produces the number 2147483647 in all cases. Why is this? I'm using gfortran (f95) on a 64-bit machine.

If I'm going to need a bignum library, which one do people suggest?

Comment: Are you declaring your variables as integer*8 ?

Comment: Iterate over a loop ~10^14 times? Do you realize how long that could take? I think you need to rethink your algorithm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The gfortran versions that I use, 4.3, 4.4 and 4.5 on a Mac, support 8-byte integers.  The best way to select a variable type in Fortran >= 90 is to use an intrinsic function to specify the precision that you need.   Try:

```
integer, parameter :: LargeInt_K = selected_int_kind (18)
integer (kind=LargeInt_K) :: i, n
```

to obtain at least 18 decimal digits, which will typically be a 8-byte integer.

With gfortran 4.3, huge (1_LargeInt_K) outputs 9223372036854775807.   When you wrote huge (1), etc., by default the constant was a default integer, here evidently 4-bytes since huge returned 2147483647.   So sometimes you need to specify the precision of constants, not just variables -- more commonly this trips people up when they lose significant figures on a real constant, which defaults to single precision.

Also see [Fortran: integer*4 vs integer(4) vs integer(kind=4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind4)

Usually gfortran has the command name gfortran.   Could f95 be a different compiler?   Try "gfortran -v" and "f95 -v".

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise huge worked like that, but it's obvious now.
I've just found out my main problem was not casting my literals, I'd write n=123456...9 (kind=blah).
Writing n=12...9_long where long=selected_int_kind(13) works fine.

Comment: One of the gfortran compile-time warning options will notify you of constants that are too large.  Try:

-fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fcheck=all  -fbacktrace

for gfortran 4.5.  or -fbounds-check for earlier versions instead of -fcheck-all

Answer (score 8):

You've misunderstood the precise definition of the `HUGE` function.  `HUGE(num)` returns the largest number with the same kind and type as `num`.  The value returned also has the same kind and type as `num`.  Since all your input values are (default) integers `HUGE`, correctly, returns the largest default-size integer.

`HUGE(num)` does not return the largest integer with `kind=num`.   Nor does `HUGE(num)` return the largest number representable in `num` bytes.  While many compilers use `integer(kind=4)` and `integer(kind=8)` *etc* for 4- and 8-byte integers, this is not guaranteed by the language standard and cannot be relied upon to be portable.

@MSB's answer tells you how to do what you want, I'm just butting in with some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:  Consider looking at compiler options.

It's been a l-o-n-g time since I've done FORTRAN, and I don't remember using HUGE(), but I looked at this a little.  My Intel Linux machine has gfortran 4.1.2.  I found I had to compile with the -fdefault-integer-8 option turned on to make it work for 64 bit integers.  Specifically, with this code:

```
      program inttest
      print *, huge(1)
      end program inttest
```

running

> $ gfortran inttest.for

created an executable which printed:

> 2147483647

However, running:

> $ gfortran -fdefault-integer-8 inttest.for

resulted in an executable which gave the output:

> 9223372036854775807

Also, when I declared a variable as integer*8 and compiled without the -fdefault-integer-8 option, I got an error.  The code:

```
  program inttest2
  integer*8  test_int
  test_int = 9223372036854775807
  print *, test_int
  end program inttest2
```

running

> $ gfortran inttest2.for

resulted in

> In file inttest.for:4
>
> ```
>   test_int = 9223372036854775807  
>                                1
> ```
>
> Error: Integer too big for its kind at (1)

However, things worked fine when I compiled with the -fdefault-integer-8 option and I got an executable which printed

> 9223372036854775807

Maybe there are other gfortran options which would be useful, but I didn't investigate further.

Granted, this still doesn't get you 10^14, but it may help explain the results you saw.

Comment: The option -fdefault-integer-8 sets the default integer to 8 bytes and is not necessary to be able to use 8 byte integers; they can be obtained via declarations.  The error message "Error: Integer too big for its kind at (1)" is telling you that the constant 9223372036854775807 is too large for its kind.  You don't need to make the default integer kind 8 bytes to solve that problem -- you can specify the type of the constant.

Comment: @M. S. B.: Thanks for explanation.  How do you specify the constant type?

Comment: The type of a constant is specified with an underscore followed by a kind value: 9223372036854775807_KindValue.  It is best to use the intrinsic selected_int_kind (for integers, or selected_real_kind for reals) to define a integer/parameter "variable" KindValue (see answer to this question) rather than relying on a specific numeric value such as 8, which can vary in meaning between compilers.