# f2py loses double precision when passing to python

Tags: python, fortran, precision, double-precision, f2py

I can't seem to get my module created with f2py to keep a number at double precision when it is passed back to python. A minimal example, with file fmodules.f90:

```
      subroutine example(output)
              implicit none
              double precision :: output
cf2py         intent(out) :: output
              output = 1.3
      end subroutine example
```

I then create the module with f2py:

```
$ f2py -c -m fmodules fmodules.f90
```

and call it from python:

```
>>> from fmodules import example
>>> example()
1.2999999523162842
```

By my count, that's about 8 digits of precision. My impression was that double precision should give about 16. I've tried all the permutations of this I can think of, including playing with the `.f2py_f2cmap` file. Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331818/does-fortran-have-inherent-limitations-on-numerical-accuracy-compared-to-other-l/3332069 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992131/precision-of-real-variable/16997380

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set output in the Fortran code using double precision,

```
output = 1.3d0
```

In Fortran 1.3 is a single precision constant.