# Check the input data type and whether it is empty or null

Tags: fortran

I am asking user to give a value at run time to do some calculations.

1. I want to test if the user entered value is a real/integer number, and if not then give a warning that the program is expecting a real/integer number here.
2. In addition, I would as well like to know how do we check if a particular variable at the moment is null or empty. i.e. I have declared a variable but what if at the time of calculation its value is null or empty or not yet set, in that case, the program shouldn't crash instead give a warning to provide a correct value.

Both these operations are much more easier in C++ and C#, but I couldn't find a way to do that in Fortran.

Comment: No wonder it is easier in C++ for you as you are asking for things that probably have no meaning in Fortran. Could you specify what you mean by null or empty declared variable?

Comment: I believe the value of an unitialised variable is undefined in C++ as well.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that "null or empty" you mean whether a variable has been initialized: "not yet set".   "null" has a particular meaning for Fortran pointer variables, but I suppose that this is not your question.
Fortran doesn't automatically give variables a special value before they are intentionally initialized so there is no easy way to check whether a variable has been initialized.   One approach is to initialize the variable its declaration with a special value.  That means that you need to know a special value that it will never obtain in the operation of the program.   One possibility is to use the `huge` intrinsic:

```
program TestVar

   real :: AVar = huge (1.0)

   if ( AVar < huge (1.0) ) then
      write (*, *) "Test 1: Good"
   else
      write (*, *) "Test 1: Bad"
   end if

   AVar = 2.2

   if ( AVar < huge (1.0) ) then
      write (*, *) "Test 2: Good"
   else
      write (*, *) "Test 2: Bad"
   end if

end program TestVar
```

As warned by @arbautjc, this only works once, even in a subroutine.  In a procedure, the initialization with declaration is only done with a first call.  Also, if you change the variable type from this example, be sure to understand how `huge` works (e.g., [Long ints in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204616/long-ints-in-fortran)).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem where my program requires the user gives input for a missing value. The way I solved it was by having a logical variable (i.e. `missing_value_set`) initialize to `.false.`. Then when parsing the command arguments set the logical variable to `.true.` when the required argument was indeed passed by the user. After parsing the arguments I have a check on that variable.

```
program main
  logical :: missing_value_set = .false.
  real :: MISS_VALUE = huge(1.0)

  ! Parse arguments
  ...

  if (.not.missing_value_set) then
    write(*, *) "ERROR: --missing argument is required"
    stop
  end if

  ! Rest of program
  ...

end program
```

No idea if that makes sense - so far it seems to work for me.