# Fortran: judge if a string is undefined before printing out

Tags: string, fortran

My goal is to print out the string when it is defined. First of all, my code is:

```
program test
   
   use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : stderr=>error_unit
   
   implicit none
   
   character(len=1024) :: file_update
   
   write (stderr, '(a)') 'file-update: '//file_update
   
end program test
```

When I run the above code, the output is:

```
file-update: �UdG��tdG�|gCG��m�F� dCG� ��3���3�P��3��UdG� �eG���eG�1
DG��UdG���g��<�CG�U��B�jdG�DG����3����3��cCG����3��dCG�<�CG����3������jdG�DG�0fCG�<�CG�0��F���G��G����F�pdG�1
DG�XmdG��pdG�ȡeG�0��F�p��3�XsdG����3����F��G����F��G��pdG�1
DG�XmdG��pdG�ȡeG�0��F�p��3�XsdG����3��7�G�
```

which means the variable `file_update` is not defined.

What I want to achieve is add an `if...else...` condition to judge if the string `file_update` is defined or not.

```
program test
   
   use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : stderr=>error_unit
   
   implicit none
   
   character(len=1024) :: file_update
   
   if (file_update is defined) then
       write (stderr, '(a)') 'file-update: '//file_update
   else
       write (stderr, '(a)') 'file-update: not defined'
   end if
   
end program test
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's not possible to check if a variable is initialised or not. Instead, you could use a `character(len=:), allocatable` string instead, and check if it is `allocated()` or not. Or you could initially set it to some dummy value, and  check whether the value has been changed or not.

Comment: You cannot. In this example you know (as the programmer) that the variable is not defined, but how one programs "defensively" to ensure that undefined variables are not referenced depends on how you intend to use the variable. Can you explain you real case further? (For example, one can set its value to the empty string and such a "bad value" can be detected when trying to open a file with that name, say.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check the input data type and whether it is empty or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446343/check-the-input-data-type-and-whether-it-is-empty-or-null)

Comment: @veryreverie, I chose to answer this question rather than agree with your duplicate (where I would have answered instead). I think this one here is a better question (although I agree with the answer to that linked question applying here): that other question asks two different things with the first being around validating input.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way within a Fortran program to test whether an arbitrary variable is undefined. It is entirely the [programmer's responsibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57558908/3157076) to ensure that undefined variables are not referenced.<sup>1</sup> Recall that "being undefined" or "becoming undefined" [doesn't mean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29737367/3157076) that there is a specific value or state we can test against.

You may be able to find a code analysis tool which helps<sup>2</sup> you in your assurance but still it remains your problem to write Fortran correctly.

How do you carefully write code to ensure you haven't referenced something you haven't defined?

- Be aware as a programmer what actions define a variable or cause it to become undefined after you defined it.
- Use default or explicit initialization to ensure a variable is *initially defined*, or early assignment to give it a value before you use it.
- With the previous, use [*sentinel/guard values*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18448744/3157076) such as values out of normal range (including NaNs).
- Using allocatable (or perhaps pointer) variables.

Your compiler may be able to help, with certain options, by initializing variables to requested sentinel values for you, automatically.

Let's look at the specific case of the question. Here, we have a character variable we want to use.

As a programmer we know we haven't yet given it a value by the time we reach the point we want to use it. We could give it an initial value which is a sentinel:

```
character(len=1024) :: file_update = ""
```

or assign such a sentinel value early on:

```
character(len=1024) :: file_update
file_update = ""
```

Then when we come to look at using the value we check it:

```
if (file_update=="") then
   error stop "Oops"
end if
```

(Beware such initialization in the first use here when there may be a second run through this part of code. Initialization is applied exactly once: initially.)

Which brings us to the first point above. What defines a variable? As a Fortran programmer you need to know this. Consider the program:

```
  implicit none
  character(255) name
  read *, name
  print *, name
end
```

When we reach the `print` statement, we've defined the `name` variable, right? We asked the user for a value, we got one and defined `name` with it, surely?

Nope.

We possibly did, but we can't guarantee that. We can't ask the compiler whether we did.

Equally, you must know what *undefines* a variable. There are easy cases, such as a dummy argument which is `intent(out)`, but less obvious cases. In

```
print *, F(Z) + A
```

for `F` a function then perhaps `Z` becomes undefined as a result of this statement. It's your responsibility to know whether that happens, not the compiler's. There is no way in Fortran to ask whether `Z` became undefined.

The Fortran standard tells you what causes a variable to become defined or undefined, to always be defined, or to be initially defined or undefined. In Fortran 2018 that's 19.6.

Which, finally, brings me to the final point: allocatable variables. You can always (ignoring the mistakes of Fortran 90) ask whether an allocatable variable is allocated:

```
  implicit none
  character(:), allocatable :: name
  ! Lots of things, maybe including the next line
  name = "somefile"
  if (.not.allocated(name)) error stop "No name given"
  ...
```

Scalars can be allocatable, and their allocation status can be queried to determine whether the variable is allocated or not. An allocatable variable can be allocated but not defined, but using an allocatable variable covers many of those cases where a non-allocatable variable would be undefined by having an allocation status we can query: an allocatable variable is initially not allocated, becomes not allocated when associated with an `intent(out)` dummy, and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup> A variable being undefined because "you haven't given it a value yet since the program started" is an easy case. However, a lot of the times a variable *becomes* undefined, instead of being initially undefined, relate to making the compiler's life easier or allowing optimizations: placing a requirement to detect and respond to such cases is counter to that.

<sup>2</sup> No tool can detect all cases of referencing an undefined variable for every possible program.