# Fortran: Integer too big for its kind

Tags: fortran

I am setting an integer to a value less than its maximum, but receiving an error that it is too big for it's kind. Why is this? Here is a sample program.

```
program max_int

integer, parameter :: i32 = selected_int_kind(32)

integer(kind = i32) :: my_int

!The largest integer of this kind
print*, huge(my_int)

!This works
my_int = 100000

!This doesn't, and gives an error.
!my_int = 1000000000000

print*, my_int

end program
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that `selected_int_kind` uses powers of 10, not 2, so you probably meant `selected_int_kind(13)` in order to resolve this number (which will also need to be 64 bit).

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204616/long-ints-in-fortran

Comment: i guess we are doomed to keep answering this so long as gfortran keeps producing that vague error message!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to append the `i32` to `1000000000000` like this: `1000000000000_i32`. gfortran complains that the number is too big for it's kind. `1000000000000` is a short integer, not a super long integer. `1000000000000_i32` is a super long integer. It is not complaining about the variable, it's complaining about the constant.

Comment: This works. But I have this integer type all over my code, to accommodate numbers ranging from 1 to this big number. Why will the code compile when I set this type of int to a smaller value, but I need the append for a value like the above?

Comment: @jgoldst1 The compiler assigns a `kind` to each constant and each variable in the code. The compiler will do the conversion from a default kind (processor dependent) to the user specified `i32` kind as long as the number falls inside the range (and precision) of the default kind. `1000000000000` as a default kind does not fit inside the range of the default kind, as so you have to force the compiler to recognize it as a `i32` kind.