# What is the size of a type "double" in fortran?

Tags: types, double, fortran

I'm trying to study chaos theory (Butterfly effect? - smallest initial condition can have adverse effects on the outcome). I book I'm following has code in Fortran, I've been assigned by my professor to try and implement the program in C++, however I can't seem to replicate the results, and so I was wondering:

What is the size of a type double in Fortran?

Thanks

Comment: I am curious: what leads you to think it's an issue with the size of a double? Perhaps some samples of the C++ and Fortran code in question?

Comment: because omission of a few significant figures can have adverse effect on the output, this is what Edward Lorenz found when he was running his weather simulations, by just rounding off from 6 significant figures to 3 showed completely different results. (See history section, paragraph 5 : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559919/force-explicit-variable-declaration-with-gfortran/3560806#3560806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "type double" you mean what used to go by the name of "double precision", then - it depends. It was commonly double of what single represented, but that also varied with your environment (the implementation of the processor).

Nowadays, (>F90 I think) those problems are usually avoided by explicitly stating a custom data type, by stating your requirements in regards of precision and data range. Check out functions SELECTED_REAL_KIND (and the links in the help from this one onward).
In short, you define a kind type, for a given range/precision.