# How to use and verify quad precision in gfortran?

Tags: fortran, precision

I am trying to use quad precision in gfortran, but it seems like the `real*16` does not work. After some fishing around, I have found that it may be implemented as `real*10`. Is `real*10` *actually* quad precision?

How can I test the precision of my code? Is there a standard simple algorithm for testing precision? For example, when I want to figure out what computer zero is, I continue to divide by 2.0 until I reach 0.0. Keeping track of the values lets me know when the computer 'thinks' that my non-zero number is zero - giving me computer zero.

Is there a good way of figuring out the precision with a type of algorithm like I described?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are really missing the information what does it mean *"does not work"*. Such formulation should never be used in good questions, because it does not tell anything useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding to the existing answers...  real*N is an extension to the language and is best not used.   real*10 is not quad precision.  Is is called "extended" -- it is a 10 byte type provided by Intel processors.   real*16 may or may not be available on gfortran, depending on compiler version, hardware and availability of libquadmath.  If provided in software, it will be slow.

The Fortran way of asking for the precision that you want is to use the selected_real_kind function to define a kind value for the precision that you want.

```
integer, parameter :: QR_K = selected_real_kind (32)
real (kind=QR_K) :: MyReal
```

Will obtain a quad real number, if it is available.   Alternatively, with Fortran 2008 or later you can "use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV" and then have access to the kind value REAL128.   The kind values will be -1 if the precision is unavailable.

A related question: [What does `real*8` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520819/what-does-real8-mean/10521611)

Comment: *"real*10 is not quad precision. Is is called "extended" -- it is a 10 byte type provided by Intel processors."* Also available on Motorola 68k chips.

Comment: Is that:
read (kind=QR_K) :: MyReal 
<or>
real (kind=QR_K) :: MyReal ?

Comment: Yes, a typo.  It should be `real`, not `read`.  Answer corrected.

Answer (score 7):

Use kinds for modern Fortran code, i.e.

```
real(some_kind_value) :: variable
```

You can then use `selected_real_kind()` or `iso_fortran_env` module or `c_long_double` kind value from `iso_c_binding` module to get the kind variable. All of these have slightly different meaning.

You can use `epsilon()`, `tiny()`, `huge()` or `nearest()` intrinsics to assess the actual precision of your code.

Quad precision in gfortran generally requires `libquadmath` library that should be available for most platforms, but maybe not by default.

Answer (score 2):

The gfortran documentation for [kind type parameters](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/KIND-Type-Parameters.html#KIND-Type-Parameters) answers this question, in particular the last sentence, which reads:

> The available kind parameters can be found in the constant arrays
>   CHARACTER_KINDS, INTEGER_KINDS, LOGICAL_KINDS and REAL_KINDS in the
>   ISO_FORTRAN_ENV module (see ISO_FORTRAN_ENV).

What you may have discovered is that `real*16` is not implemented on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

real(kind=10) is the so-called extended 80-bit precision [Wikipedia 80-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format).

real(kind=16) is the proper quadruple 128-bit precition [Wikipedia 128-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format).

As already mentioned, you can employ selected_real_kind(), epsilon(), tiny(), huge() to select and check the precision to be used.

Comment: A caution: using specific numeric values for kind parameters is not portable across compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the gfortran command

> gfortran -fdefault-real-8 test.f -o test.exe

on the test file

```
      implicit double precision(a-h,o-z)
 1    continue
      print * , ' i:'
      read(5,*) i
      if(i.le.0) stop
      a=i
      b=sqrt(a)
      print * , b
      c=b*b
      print * , c
      goto 1
      end
```

On my platform (FEDORA 20) it works.

Comment: This is really awful. The side-effect having ALL the double precision variables as quad precision can be very annoying. I also bet that if `real*16` does not work, this actually will not promote the doubles the quad and thus won't solve the original problem.