# Numerical Integral of large numbers in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran90, numerical, largenumber

so I have the following Integral that i need to do numerically:

```
Int[Exp(0.5*(aCosx + bSinx + cCos2x + dSin2x))] x=0..2Pi
```

The problem is that the output at any given value of x can be extremely large, e^2000, so larger than I can deal with in double precision.

I havn't had much luck googling for the following, how do you deal with large numbers in fortran, not high precision, i dont care if i know it to beyond double precision, and at the end i'll just be taking the log, but i just need to be able to handle the large numbers untill i can take the log..

Are there integration packes that have the ability to handle arbitrarily large numbers? Mathematica clearly can.. so there must be *something* like this out there.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

This is probably an extended comment rather than an answer but here goes anyway ...

As you've already observed Fortran isn't equipped, out of the box, with the facility for handling such large numbers as `e^2000`.  I think you have 3 options.

1. Use mathematics to reduce your problem to one which does (or a number of related ones which do) fall within the numerical range that your Fortran compiler can compute.
2. Use *Mathematica* or one of the other *computer algebra systems* (eg Maple, SAGE, Maxima).  All (I think) of these can be integrated into a Fortran program (with varying degrees of difficulty and integration).
3. Use a library for *high-precision* (often called either *arbitray-precision* or *multiple-precision* too) arithmetic.  Your favourite search engine will turn up a number of these for you, some written in Fortran (and therefore easy to integrate), some written in C/C++ or other languages (and therefore slightly harder to integrate).  You might start your search at [Lawrence Berkeley](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/) or [the GNU bignum library](http://gmplib.org).
4. (Yes I know that I wrote that you have 3 options, but your question suggests that you aren't ready to consider this yet) You could write your own high-/arbitrary-/multiple-precision functions.  Fortran provides everything you need to construct such a library, there is a lot of work already done in the field to learn from, and it might be something of interest to you.

In practice it generally makes sense to apply as much mathematics as possible to a problem before resorting to a computer, that process can not only assist in solving the problem but guide your selection or construction of a program to solve what's left of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with High Peformance Mark that the best option here numerically is to use analytics to scale or simplify the result first.

I will mention that if you do want to brute force it, gfortran (as of 4.6, with the [libquadmath](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/) library) has support for [quadruple precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) reals, which you can use by [selecting the appropriate kind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400323/463827).  As long as your answers (and the intermediate results!) don't get too much bigger than what you're describing, that may work, but it will generally be much slower than double precision.

Answer (score 1):

This requires looking deeper at the problem you are trying to solve and the behavior of the underlying mathematics. To add to the good advice already provided by Mark and Jonathan, consider expanding the exponential and trig functions into Taylor series and truncating to the desired level of precision.

Also, take a step back and ask why you are trying to accomplish by calculating this value. As an example, I recently had to debug why I was getting outlandish results from a property correlation which was calculating vapor pressure of a fluid to see if condensation was occurring. I spent a long time trying to understand what was wrong with the temperature being fed into the correlation until I realized the case causing the error was a simulation of vapor detonation. The problem was not in the numerics but in the logic of checking for condensation during a literal explosion; physically, a condensation check made no sense. The real problem was the code was asking an unnecessary question; it already had the answer.

I highly recommend Forman Acton's  [Numerical Methods That (Usually) Work](http://books.google.com/books/about/Numerical_Methods_that_Usually_Work.html?id=YHXU4W3Ez2MC) and [Real Computing Made Real](http://books.google.com/books?id=LhFRAAAACAAJ). Both focus on problems like this and suggest techniques to tame ill-mannered computations.