# precision of real variable

Tags: fortran, precision

I have the following code in FORTRAN 77:

```
REAL*8 :: dm

dm=1.-1.E-12

write(6,*) 'dm: ', dm
```

I get: `dm: 1`

Is this OK? I would like to get `dm=0.999999999999`

Comment: I don't know enough about FORTRAN to answer authoritatively, but assuming that REAL*8 represents an 8 byte float (double precision) it should have at least 15 digits of precision. Could it have something to do with the output formatting?

Comment: The trouble is your constants are single precision, try 1.D0-1.D-12. Note that notation (along with REAL*8) is obsolete in modern fortran but still works. Not clear if/why you want f77..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in a comment, you need to specify the precision of the constants.  Also, `real*8` is obsolete.   (Was it always an extension?)    Here is a modern way to write this, using the ISO Fortran Environment to obtain a 64-bit real type and using that type both in the declaration and in the constants.

```
use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV

real (real64) :: dm  
dm = 1.0_real64 - 1.0E-12_real64
```

For more info, see [What does `real*8` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520819/what-does-real8-mean/)