# Portable declaration of REAL variables in mex gateway for Fortran

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex, matlab-deployment

I am writing a mex gateway for a piece of Fortran code.

In the Fortran code, for portability, the floating-point variables are declared as

```
REAL(kind(0.0D0)) :: x, y, etc
```

(BTW, I am aware that there are better ways to do it, as discussed at 
[Fortran: integer*4 vs integer(4) vs integer(kind=4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4),
[What does "real*8" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520819/what-does-real8-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1), and 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2017/03/27/doctor-fortran-in-it-takes-all-kinds )

However, it seems to me that mex supports only REAL*8 and REAL*4, the former being Double, the latter being Single. I got this impression from the following functions/subroutines:

mxIsDouble, mxIsSingle, mxCopyPtrToReal8, mxCopyReal8ToPtr, mxCopyPtrToReal4, mxCopyReal4ToPtr

My questions are as follows.

1. Is it true that mex supports only REAL*8 and REAL*4?
2. Does it improve the portability of the mex gateway if I declare double-precision floating-point variables as

   REAL(kind(0.0D0)) :: x, y, etc

or even

```
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
real(kind=dp) :: x, y, etc
```

Or should I simply declare

```
REAL*8 :: x, y, etc
```

3. Are REAL*8 and/or REAL*4 supported on all platforms? If no, does this mean that MATLAB mex is intrinsically unportable?
4. What is the best way to specify the kind of floating-point variables in mex gateways for Fortran code?

The following code is an example. See the declaration of x, y, and xs.

```
#include "fintrf.h"

      subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)
C     y = square (x) 
C     x: a floating point scalar
C     y: x^2

      implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments 
      integer, intent(in) :: nlhs, nrhs 
      mwPointer, intent(in) :: prhs(nrhs)
      mwPointer, intent(inout) :: plhs(nlhs)

C     function declarations:
      mwPointer, external :: mxCreateDoubleScalar, mxGetPr
      mwSize, external :: mxGetM, mxGetN
      integer*4, external :: mxIsDouble, mxIsSingle 

C     variables
      mwSize, parameter :: mwOne = 1
      integer, parameter :: dKind = kind(0.0D0) 
      integer, parameter :: sKind = kind(0.0) 
      real(kind=dKind) :: x, y ! Does this improve the portablity?
      real(kind=sKind) :: xs ! Does this improve the portablity?

C     validate number of arguments
      if (nrhs .ne. 1) then
         call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt ('mex:nInput', '1 input required.')
      endif
      if (nlhs .gt. 1) then
         call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt ('mex:nOutput', 'At most 1 output.')
      endif

C     validate input
      if (mxIsDouble(prhs(1)) .ne. 1 .and. mxIsSingle(prhs(1)) .ne. 1) 
      ! What if the input is a floating point number but neither Double nor Single? 
     + then 
          call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt ('mex:Input', 'Input a real number.')
      endif
      if (mxGetM(prhs(1)) .ne. 1 .or. mxGetN(prhs(1)) .ne. 1) then
          call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt ('mex:Input', 'Input a scalar.')
      endif

C     read input
      if (mxIsDouble(prhs(1)) .eq. 1) then
         call mxCopyPtrToReal8(mxGetPr(prhs(1)), x, mwOne) 
      else
         call mxCopyPtrToReal4(mxGetPr(prhs(1)), xs, mwOne)
         x = real(xs, dKind) 
         ! What if the input is a floating point number but neither REAL*8 nor REAL*4
      endif

C     do the calculation
      y = x**2

C     write output
      plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleScalar(y)

      return
      end subroutine mexFunction
```

The code runs correctly. Yet I am not sure whether it is portable.

Comment: Maybe also `real*4 single; real(kind(single)) x`.  Just as unportable, but limiting the number of parts to worry about.

Comment: "does this mean that MATLAB mex is intrinsically unportable?". MATLAB is available only for 3 OSes, and [the documentation lists exactly which version of which compilers you can use to make MEX-files](https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html). So yes, MEX is intrinsically unportable, in that you cannot compile MEX-files on other platforms or with other compilers.

Comment: Thank you, @francescalus and Cris Luengo, for the informative comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REAL*4` and `REAL*8` are non-standard and non-portable. `REAL(KIND(0.0D0)` gets you `DOUBLE PRECISION` on every platform, as this is required by the Fortran standard.

I can't speak to MEX gateways, but you should avoid obvious non-standard features.

A popular choice is to define a module that declares named (PARAMETER) constants for the kinds in use. For example:

`module kinds
integer, parameter :: SP = KIND(0.0)
integer, parameter :: DP = KIND(0.0D0)
end module kinds`

Then you can use `SP` and `DP` as kind values. If you ever need to change these, just edit the module.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. May I ask two more questions? Q1. Is REAL(DP) equivalent to REAL*8 and REAL(SP) equivalent to REAL*4 on ALL platforms?  Q2. How should I declare INTEGER*4 in a similar way?  I ask these questions because mex explicitly requires REAL*8, REAL*4, and INTEGER*4. Thank you very much!

Comment: I would say that whoever wrote those "requirements" needs to be sent in for reeducation. Seriously, you can interpret "REAL*4" as "single precision" and "REAL*8" as "double precision". On compilers that support those extensions, that's what they mean. As for INTEGER*4, you could use KIND(0), though I might actually recommend use of the standard intrinsics SELECTED_INT_KIND and SELECTED_REAL_KIND, with appropriate values for arguments.

Comment: Thanks again, @Steve Lionel. I totally agree with the reeducation --- these nonstandard things cause me a lot a headache. Sorry to bother you with a final question about the "appropriate values for arguments": Is it correct that SELECTED_INT_KIND(7), SELECTED_INT_KIND(8), SELECTED_INT_KIND(9) will all give us INTEGER*4, SELECTED_INT_KIND(6, 37) will give us REAL*4, and SELECTED_INT_KIND(15,307) will give us REAL*8? I read these values from elsewhere, yet it would be great to hear opinions from a true expert. Thank you very much!

Comment: I assume you meant to say SELECTED_REAL_KIND for the real types. Those are the values I would use (9 for INT), though I know of a platform (in an unusual configuration) where (15,307) would not get what you want. An alternative (though I don't like it) is the INT32, REAL32 and REAL64 constants from intrinsic module ISO_FORTRAN_ENV. (I have some philosophical objections to how these are often used, but they work in your case.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, `KIND` was introduced in Fortran 90. I'm pretty sure that most of the Fortran code in MATLAB is from before then. When the `REAL*8` code was written, it was the correct way of doing so. I would even bet that, besides Cleve himself, there's no Fortran programmers working at the MathWorks, and there haven't been any in a loooong time.

Comment: `REAL*8` was never standard. The pre-F90 way of expressing that was `DOUBLE PRECISION`

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it makes no difference whether you define variables as REAL*8/REAL*4 or REAL(REAL64)/REAL(REAL32). In the future MathWorks may come around and rewrite their functions to use portable variable declarations, but in my opinion this is unlikely for many reasons.

If you look in the `fintrf.h` file (included in every Fortran MEX gateway source file), you'll see that all of the MEX-specific procedures are defined with "asterisk notation," e.g. `# define MWPOINTER INTEGER*8`. So even if you define all of your variables with kinds from iso_fortran_env or selected_real_kind, any time you use a MathWorks variable type you're still using "asterisk notation" types, unless you go through that header file and redefine every symbol using your chosen kind specification.

Comment: Indeed. It's easier to follow the notation of the header files you use.