# Speed of separated vs. combined variable declaration in Fortran 90?

Tags: performance, coding-style, fortran, declaration

Is there any performance advantage to declare multiple variables by one single statement compared to using separate statements for the declaration?

This question could be interesting for choosing between a lazy

```
REAL(kind=8), ALLOCATABLE :: x(:,:,:) , &
                     &       y(:,:,:) , &
                     &       z(:,:,:)
```

and a more explicit programming style

```
REAL(kind=8), ALLOCATABLE :: x(:,:,:)
REAL(kind=8), ALLOCATABLE :: y(:,:,:)
REAL(kind=8), ALLOCATABLE :: z(:,:,:)
```

Is the answer the same for global variables shared via modules and for local variables declared in subroutines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There cannot be any difference in speed. These declarations of the variables are 100% equivalent.

Also please do not use `kind=8`, it does not do, what you probably think it does. In particular it is not equivalent with `real*8` nor with `double precision` ([Fortran: integer*4 vs integer(4) vs integer(kind=4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4)).