# How to efficiently convert a Fortran array before calling a C routine

Tags: algorithm, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

Suppose I have the following Fortran subroutine:

```
subroutine f_test(n,x,value)

    use iso_c_binding

    implicit none

    integer,      intent(in)  :: n
    real(kind=8), intent(in)  :: x(n)
    real(kind=8), intent(out) :: value

    integer(kind=c_int) :: n_
    real(kind=c_double) :: value_,x_(n)

    n_     = transfer( n, n_ )
    x(1:n) = transfer( x(1:n), x_(1:n) )

    call c_test(n_,x_,value_)

    value = transfer( value_, value )

end subroutine f_test
```

and also suppose that `c_test` is a pointer to a C routine that works over the vector `x` and returns a result in `value` variable.

This works perfectly, but I have a question about it:

The conversion of the vector `x` can dramatically affect the complexity of an algorithm that calls the subroutine `f_test`. I mean that, if a such algorithm calls `f_test` `n` times, the complexity of the algorithm will be quadratic, but without this conversion, it would be simply linear. So, this conversion made in this way is impracticable. Is there any reasonable way to work around this issue?

Comment: What exactly does c_test do that it's O(1) complexity?

Comment: Actually, the complexity of `c_test` is not supposed to be O(1). Sorry, I didn't express correctly. The concern is not with the complexity of `f_test`, but with the call `x(1:n) = transfer( x(1:n), x_(1:n) )`. This is supposed to consume O(n) time, since I am copying a vector of size `n`. What I meant is that without this conversion, I would have no extra time consumption.

Comment: Right, but if the complexity of c_test is also O(n), I just don't see the concern here, unless the work done in c_test is less than that of a (possibly converting) assignment, which strikes me as unlikely.  And even if that is the case, if c_test is that trivial it's probably easy to re-implement in fortran.

Answer (score 3):

The Fortran intrinsic `transfer` doesn't convert numeric types, it just copies bits, bypassing types.  No conversion is taking place.  If `integer` and `integer (c_int)` should be different types, or `real (kind=8)` and `real (c_double)` different types, a conversion would be necessary but will not be done by transfer.   An assignment statement or an intrinsic function such as `int` or `real` could effect a conversion.

I assume that you use `real (kind=8)` to mean an 8-byte real.  There is no guarantee that the kind value of 8 corresponds to that type.  This has been discussed several times on Stackoverflow, e.g., [Fortran: integer*4 vs integer(4) vs integer(kind=4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4)

The type `integer` without qualification and `integer (c_int)` might be the same, in which case no conversion is necessary.   Similar for the others ... in which case the compiler will likely accept `call c_test(n,x,value)`, recognizing that the types are identical, since the numeric values of the kinds are the same, even though different symbols were used.  To be more portable, you could the `int` and `real` intrinsic function for the input arguments  and use an assignment for the output:

```
call c_test ( int (n, c_int), real (x, c_double), value_)
value = value_
```

If you want to be sure that no conversions take place, you could use `integer (c_int)`, `real (c_double)`, etc., throughout you Fortran code.  This would also give you a portable way of specifying an 8-byte real. (Which can also be done by using ISO_FORTRAN_ENV.)

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer! My main concern is the case when `c_double` is not `8`. In these cases, it would be required to make the type conversion, and by calling `real(x, c_double)`, I am affraid to dramatically change the complexity of my algorithm (since this conversion seems to have linear time consumption in `n`, instead of a constant one). Do you think that is there a way to convert `x` in constant time (someway working with pointers, for example)?

Comment: Pointers won't help.  If the variables are one type, and you need another type, a conversion will be necessary.  If this makes your program too slow, you could either have the Fortran use `real (c_double)` instead of `real (8)` [which, in any case, is non-portable] everywhere or you could rewrite c_test in Fortran.   Have you measured the execution time?  Is this area slow and a significant fraction of the run time?

Comment: No, I didn't measured the time. Actually, I have a legacy code in Fortran and I am developing only the C interface. What is known is that `n` can be potentially large, and this C routine can be called `n` times. So, such conversions certanly will make the code slower. No problem, at all. I guess that, in general, `c_double = 8`, and I can even omit the conversion. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using transfer?  If the C routine can work directly with the internal representation of x, then just pass it x.  If you are converting from kind 8 to kind c_double, then just use assignment.

Does the C routine modify x or n (does it take n by value?)?  Assuming not, and assuming tthat the use of transfer is not for some other unstated reason - on many platforms, the value of C_double is 8 and the default integer kind is the value of c_int.  A shortcut would be worthwhile.

```
if (kind(x) == c_double .and. kind(n) == c_int) then
  call c_test(n, x, value)
else
  n_ = n
  x_ = x
  call c_test(n_, x_, value_)
  value = value_
end if
```

Comment: OK, this looks like a good workaround, thanks! But since `x` is a vector of size `n`, the assignment may consume `O(n)` time. Do you think is there another way to avoid this (something that consume constant time to execute)?