# Fortran improper output on AIX and Linux

Tags: linux, fortran, precision, aix, intel-fortran

I have a scenario where i declare a variable real*8 and read a value

0.1234123412341234

which is stored in a file.

When i try to read it on Linux to a variable and display the value, it prints

0.12341234123412

whereas when i run the same code for AIX it prints the value

0.12341234123412370

Why does both the platform print different values for the same code? Is there any possibility to overcome this without using format specifier?

P.S

AIX compiler is xlf

Linux compiler is ifort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using list-directed IO, `write (X, *)`.  While this type of IO is convenient, the output is not fully specified by the standard.   If you want your output to be extremely similar across compilers and platforms, you should use a format.  (You might still have small variations in results due to the use of finite-precision arithmetic.)

Comment: I understand that using the format helps in maintaining the consistency of values. But i have a program with multiple write statements, so do you think there is a possibility of specifying at compile time? Or is there any way to overcome this other than changing the actual code like using compiler options or so?

Comment: I've never seen compiler options to control the behavior of list-directed IO.  If you want to control IO, you need to use a format.  You can use a labeled format statement and share it between many write statements ... that way there is only one format to update should you wish to change the output.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `REAL*8` for declaring double variables, you should use

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: prec = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,307)
REAL(prec) :: variable
```

to specify a portable double-precision variables ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3170438/1276356) for more details).

In any event, the problem you are experiencing is related to [precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64). A double-precision variable can go to 15 digits before becoming wrong, which appears to be the case with both compilers. In fact, I would argue that these are indeed the same number because of how close they are (a % difference of about 3E-12).

Comment: I agree that the values that both the compilers show are the same due to the minimal difference, but the problem I have is that I want the linux output to show the same output as AIX. I am dealing with a program where every decimal digit counts. So I am trying to make linux equal to AIX, since AIX is more accurate. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If 15th decimal place precision counts, then go to quadruple precision and not worry about the 16th decimal place and onwards. I also would not say that "AIX is more accurate" since you are comparing the 16th digits of a only-to-15-digits accurate representations of numbers.