# Is there a difference when declaring a variable with a double colon

Tags: fortran, fortran90

When declaring variables is there a difference when using a double colon?

```
real(8) :: a
real(8) b
```

Both of these apparently do the same thing. Is there any difference between these besides style?

I know we can initialize variables and add attributes as follows

```
real(8), intent(in), parameter :: a = 4, b = 2
```

but besides that, is there any difference when just declaring a plain old `real` or `integer` with no attributes and not initializing?

Also, does this have anything to do with the `SAVE` attribute? A while back in some of my code was behaving unexpectedly and I was saving the results of a function between calls, which forced me to explicitly set the variable to zero each time the function was called, even though the `SAVE` attribute was not set by me.

Comment: I do not recommend using `real(8)` directly. Use a named constant and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your first example the `::` is not needed and can be omitted. The general syntax is:

```
type-spec [ [,attr-spec]... :: ] entities
```

In your first case:

```
type-spec: real(8)
entities: a and b
```

The square brackets in the syntax definition mean that that part is optional. If however you specify an `attr-spec` (like `intent(in)` or `parameter`), then the `::` is required. Specifically:

```
[ [, attr-spec] :: ]
```

means that the `::` is optional and `attr-spec` is optional, but if you give and `attr-spec` you MUST also give the `::`.

I suspect people just get into the habit of providing the `::` for every declaration.

In the example:

```
real :: a=4.5
```

The `=4.5` forces `a` to be `SAVE`ed which may cover the second part of your question.

Comment: That's exactly it, the default save behavior was unexpected. Looking at the ifort documentation again answers all my questions. The **:: can be excluded** and save is default for **Non scalar local variables**. My variable was an array which leads me to believe that was the issue if arrays are not scalar.

Comment: It may be worth explicitly saying that initialization also requires the `::` as well as implying `SAVE`.