# Declaring an integer FORTRAN

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm new to Fortran, and sorry for this noobish question, I didn't find an answer for it.
In the code:

```
  integer ( kind = 4 ) k
  integer ( kind = 4 ) v(k)
  integer ( kind = 4 ) list(*)
```

What does (k) and (*) do in the second, third line?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first integer, `k` is a scalar.  The second integer `v(k)` is an array `v` with `k` elements. The last integer `list(*)` an assumed size array that is a dummy argument to a procedure.  Its length (number of elements) will be determined by the actual argument passed to the procedure.

Note that `kind = 4` is not portable and you should instead use the intrinsics `kind()` or `selected_int_kind()` to specify the size of your integers.

Comment: `list(*)` is an assumed size array and the user must now the size from some other variable.

Comment: As stated, `kind=4` is not portable.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4

Comment: As Vladimir suggests, you cannot invoke the SIZE intrinsic on an assumed size array.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing the answer of @casey:

The definition of

```
INTEGER(KIND=4) list(*)
```

is only valid as definition of a dummy argument. Though, you can define this list with the help of a *constant* as a named constant (specified by the `PARAMETER` keyword):

```
INTEGER(KIND=4), PARAMETER :: list(*) = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

In this case, this is called an *implied-shape array* (5.3.8.6) which gets its length implicitely from the constant array.

Comment: Although an implied-shape array must be a named constant.