# Fortran: efficient conversion of KIND=8 array to KIND=4

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I am using an external fortran library that returns a large array of data with the type`REAL(kind=8)`. However, I need to write the data out as `REAL(kind=4)`.

What is the best way to convert large arrays of data to a different `KIND` type?

I am naively just doing this at the moment:

```
REAL(KIND=8), ALLOCATABLE :: data64(:,:)
REAL(KIND=4), ALLOCATABLE :: data32(:,:)

# allocate arrays and call external function
CALL some_external_function(data64)

# Convert to 32bit using simple assignment
data32 = data64

# Write out 32bit data....
WRITE(UOUT) data32
```

However, this approach requires me to allocate two large arrays instead of one and do a lot of copying of data - seems a bit inefficient with both respect to memory and processing...

Is there a smarter way?

BTW: The sizes of the matrices are not necessarily huge - they vary but probably in the order of around 1000 x 1000 (but this will be occuring 100s of times in a loop). Not a problem for modern machines, but as one of the comments suggests, I am looking for an *elegant* solution that is also efficient! Doing the assignement just seems.....lazy and inelagant?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I am writing out an unformatted (binary) file; it needs to be KIND=4 as other programs expect the data in this format.

Comment: IF you are doing `I/O` the speed for the conversion wouldn't matter as it is going to be orders of magnitude faster then disk writing. Maybe you want the most _elegant_ solution instead of the most _efficient_.

Comment: What about converting one row at a time and then appending that row in the file.

Comment: Oh, btw, what is approximately the size of these matrices?

Comment: @ja72 - yes, I suppose I want the elegant solution! Have edited my post.

Comment: Just my usual rant why `kind=4` and `kind=8` are ugly [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4?lq=1. Heck it is even longer than `real(sp)` and `real(dp)`, I simply don't get why would anybody continue to use them.

Comment: @VladimirF - I had not realised that `kind=x` types were not portable. Code smell indeed....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's elegant for you

```
write(uout) real(data64,kind(data32))
```

Comment: Do you mean `real(data64, kind(data32))` here, rather than int?

Comment: I did not know you could use `int()` and `real()` like that. Thank you!