# f2py triggers malloc error

Tags: python, memory, fortran, f2py

I am currently wrapping fortran code with `f2py`. However, even some simple tests will trigger malloc error. For example:

```
! file name is simple.F90
SUBROUTINE test(aout, ain, rank)
    INTEGER :: rank
    COMPLEX(kind=16) :: ain(rank, rank)
    COMPLEX(kind=16), INTENT(out) :: aout(rank, rank)
    print *, ain
    aout = ain
END SUBROUTINE test
```

I wrapped this code with `f2py -m simple -c simple.F90` and used it:

```
import simple
import numpy as np
ain = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]],dtype="complex")
simple.test(ain,2)
```

The output is rather confusing:

```
(2.98323129689261721470924741607413318E-4947,0.00000000000000000000000000000000000) (0.00000000000000000000000000000000000,2.98323129689261721470924741607413318E-4947) (5.43913343041483495234482095052061699E-4937,1.19445898260724927749750105155089048E-4946) (2.03058027046167518900674768173335535E-4945,5.42471021397611822645684765587671432E-4937)
Python(9481,0x7fff7ad40000) malloc: \*** error for object 0x7fabcaa1adc8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Fortran subroutine is not getting the correct array and something's wrong with the memory.

More information:

- OS: OS X
- python: 3.5.1

Comment: I think it should be `kind=8` not `kind=16` (it looks to specify the precision of each part of the complex number). However, I don't know if that's what is causing your error.

Comment: There are many answers here on SO which point out that the kind number is an arbitrary integer value.  When it comes to complex numbers it is almost certain that a kind number of `16` WILL NOT map to a complex number with 2 8-byte elements.  The kind of a complex number is the same as the kind of a real number capable of representing each component of the complex number.  i.e. if you think of a complex number as being 2 reals of `kind=3` (say) then that complex number ought also to have `kind=3`.

Comment: Obligatory links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4?lq=1 Any `(kind=number)` is a code smell. Use named constants. If you omit the `kind=` it will still be shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the comments pointed out, `kind` is what to be blamed here. All problems resolved after I use the following convention.

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
REAL(kind=dp) :: a_real_number
COMPLEX(kind=dp) :: a_complex_number
```