# Overflow in a random number generator and 4-byte vs. 8-byte integers

Tags: random, fortran

The famous linear congruential random number generator also known as minimal standard use formula

```
x(i+1)=16807*x(i) mod (2^31-1)
```

I want to implement this using Fortran.

However, as pointed out by "Numerical Recipes", directly implement the formula with default Integer type (32bit) will cause `16807*x(i)` to overflow.

So the book recommend Schrage’s algorithm is based on an approximate factorization of m. This method can still implemented with default integer type.

However, I am wondering fortran actually has `Integer(8)` type whose range is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` which is much bigger than `16807*x(i)` could be.

but the book even said the following sentence

> It is not possible to implement equations (7.1.2) and (7.1.3) directly
>   in a high-level language, since the product of a and m − 1 exceeds the
>   maximum value for a 32-bit integer.

**So why can't we just use `Integer(8)` type to implement the formula directly?**

Comment: `Integer(8)` does not mean 8-byte integer, but integer of kind 8. It is not the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4

Comment: Regarding Numerical Recipes see http://www.uwyo.edu/buerkle/misc/wnotnr.html . Simply don't believe them for this. It is an old book and wasn't that good even when it was written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you can have 8-byte integers depends on your compiler and your system. What's worse is that the actual value to pass to `kind` to get a specific precision is not standardized. While most Fortran compilers I know use the number of bytes (so 8 would be 64 bit), this is not guaranteed.

You can use the [`selected_int_kind`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SELECTED_005fINT_005fKIND.html)method to get a kind of `int` that has a certain range. This code compiles on my 64 bit computer and works fine:

```
program ran
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: i8 = selected_int_kind(R=18)
    integer(kind=i8) :: x
    integer :: i
    x = 100
    do i = 1, 100
        x = my_rand(x)
        write(*, *) x
    end do

    contains
        function my_rand(x)
            implicit none
            integer(kind=i8), intent(in) :: x
            integer(kind=i8) :: my_rand
            my_rand = mod(16807_i8 * x, 2_i8**31 - 1)
        end function my_rand
end program ran
```

**Update and explanation of @VladimirF's comment below**

Modern Fortran delivers an intrinsic module called `iso_fortran_env` that supplies constants that reference the standard variable types. In your case, one would use this:

```
program ran
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: int64
    implicit none
    integer(kind=int64) :: x
```

and then as above. This code is easier to read than the old `selected_int_kind`. (Why did `R` have to be 18 again?)

Comment: Thank you chw21. So the saying of the book is wrong, the formula can be directly implemented in fortran, right?

Comment: @user15964 Yes, you can. To select 8 bytes directly you can use `kind=int64` where `int64` is defined in intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The simplest thing is to append `_8` to the integer constants to make them 8 bytes. I know it is "old style" Fortran but is is portable and unambiguous.

By the way, when you write:

```
16807*x mod (2^31-1)
```

this is equivalent to take the result of `16807*x` and use an `and` with a 32-bit mask where all the bits are set to one except the sign bit.
The efficient way to write it by avoiding the expensive mod functions is:

```
iand(16807_8*x, Z'7FFFFFFF')
```

**Update after comment** :

or

```
iand(16807_8*x, 2147483647_8)
```

if your super modern compiler does not have backwards compatibility.

Comment: It is not portable. `_8` is not accepted by certain compilers which  have kinds `1,2,3`. `_8` DOES NOT mean 8 bytes, it means `kind=8`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4  And it is not old style (it only works in Fortran 90 and newer), it is just bad style.

Comment: I am also strongly convinced there are problems with your  `iand(16807_8*x, Z'7FFFFFFF')`. The usage of BOZ constants were changed in Fortran 2008 and are more general now but still I am quite sure that the BOZ constant in your example is quadruple precision (in my compiler) and mixing it this way is not allowed.

Comment: OK. Thanks for correcting. Fortran seems to deviate so much from Fortran90! It reminds me of the Python2 vs Python3 conflict...

Comment: No, Fortran 90 did not allow a BOZ constant in your expression at all. It is completely invalid there. Fortran 2008 just allowed them to appear in more contexts.

Comment: As of Fortran 2008, BOZ literal constant in a reference to `iand` is converted to a value that has the same kind as the other argument (both arguments may not be BOZ literals).  That reference looks ok to me.  BOZ literals do not have a type or kind in their own right in the standard language - that is always inferred from the contexts in which they can be used.

Comment: Please don't use hard-coded kind numbers such as _8. Not all compilers use 8 as the kind for this integer size. Define a PARAMETER constant, such as I64, with the value SELECTED_INT_KIND(15). Then use _I64 as the kind specifier.

Comment: @IanH I know that they do not have a kind per se. Could you show me the standard reference? Perhaps a bug should be reported to gfortran then.

Comment: @VladimirF F2008 C4102, plus the various descriptions of what happens where BOZ literals are permitted.