# Rounding large floats to integer

Tags: floating-point, fortran, rounding, gfortran

In Fortran, I want to be able to round a large double precision float to the nearest integer. I attempt this as follows,

```
PROGRAM rounding
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = 8
REAL(KIND=DP) :: value

value = 12345678987.123456

print *, CEILING(value)

END PROGRAM ROUNDING
```

However, this does not output the correct answer, but instead gives `-2147483648`. I appreciate that this is related to the nature and precision of floating points, but rounding a number like this seems a reasonable goal.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Minor note: if `value` is a double precision number, it is better to write `value = 12345678987.123456_dp`. Without the `_dp`, you are assigning a single precision number to `value` and some of the digits are lost. In your case, the difference in the resulting integer is `12345678848` vs `12345678988`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer variable returned by `ceiling()` is of a too small kind to contain the value. You have to tell ceiling to produce an integer of a larger kind. Otherwise it uses the default integer.

For example by

```
print *, CEILING(value, kind=dp)
```

(assuming there exist such kind, but it should exist, if `DP` is selected sensibly)

Do note that `kind=8` is ugly and not portable. You should not use literal constants such as `8`. There is no guarantee that any such kind exist.

So I would use:

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = kind(1.d0)
```

For the integer kind you can use [SELECTED_INT_KIND](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SELECTED_005fINT_005fKIND.html) to select the kind with enough digits like

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: IP = SELECTED_INT_KIND(15)

print *, CEILING(value, kind=IP)
```

or use any other method from [Fortran: integer*4 vs integer(4) vs integer(kind=4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4)

Comment: The original question asks for 'nearest integer', which is more like `NINT` than `CEILING`. But the rest of the answer, which is the important part, is correct.