# How to convert from one Fortran integer kind to a smaller one?

Tags: fortran, integer, converters, gfortran

I need to convert a parameter from `integer(kind=8)` to `integer(kind=4)` in Fortran, is there any (simple) way of doing this?

This parameter is an input number, and if this number is greater than 2^31-1 (the limit of a 4-byte integer), the program will always ask for a smaller number (so it can "fit" inside those 4 bytes), so I think that this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: why not just use the larger type for everything?

Answer (score 2):

To create integer of any kind use

```
result = int(source, kind=result_kind)
```

so you can do

```
result = int(source, 4)
```

`source` can be any number, including an integer of any kind.

Note that `kind=8` does not mean 8 bytes and `kind=4` does not mean 4 bytes. There are compilers which do not have kinds 4 and 8 at all. These numbers are not portable. Do not use them. See [Fortran: integer*4 vs integer(4) vs integer(kind=4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As [Vladimir F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47123269/3157076) notes, the intrinsic function `int` returns an integer value of desired kind `int(i,kind=kind)`.

When an expression of a certain kind is required (such as in a procedure argument list) this is quite useful:

```
call sub_with_int_i1_arg(INT(int_i2, kind=i1))
```

However, intrinsic assignment to an integer already provides conversion if required:

```
  integer, parameter :: kind1=7, kind2=23
  integer(kind1) :: i
  integer(kind2) :: j = 85

! The intrinsic assignment
  i = j
! is equivalent to
  i = INT(j,KIND(i))
! which here is also
  i = INT(j,kind1)
end
```

The intrinsic `huge` may be useful in determining whether the range of `i` is large enough:

```
if (ABS(j).le.HUGE(i)) then
  i = j
else
  error stop "Oh noes :("
end if
```

As Steve Lionel commented about the draft, Fortran 2018 introduced the intrinsic function `out_of_range` which also tests such cases:

```
if (.not.OUT_OF_RANGE(j,i)) then
  i = j
else
  error stop "Oh noes :("
end if
```

However, even in early 2022 it's not wise to rely on implementation of this function.

Comment: I'll also note that Fortran 2018 will add an OUT_OF_RANGE intrinsic function that lets you ask if a value of one integer or real kind is representable in another integer or real kind, with or without rounding.