# Integer precision

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I was solving Project Euler problems using Fortran; the problem is to create a Fibonacci sequence and find the sum of all even numbers that come under 4 million. Here's what I wrote

```
implicit none
integer*4::a(1:4000000),sum
integer*4::i,maxc
maxc = 3999999

a(1) = 1
a(2) = 2
do i = 3,maxc,1
   a(i) = a(i-1) + a(i-2)
end do
sum = 0
do i = 1,maxc
   if (mod(a(i),2)==0) then
      sum = sum + a(i)
   end if
end do
print*,sum


end
```

The output is `-1833689714`
Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Also, please note that using `integer*4` is not well defined across compilers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the size of the integer kind you chose, there is a limit to the numbers you can represent. 
In your code it is `2147483647` (with `gfortran`, obtained by `print *,huge(sum)`). 
It can be shown that this limit is exceeded for `i=59` in your implementation. 
Then, you get an integer overflow, and the value becomes negative.

Simply using a floating point representation for the sum, i.e.

```
real :: sum
```

Does the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't double precision be better?

Comment: @albert: In this case, the outcome is small enough to fit into the range of a single precision float. One could argue that the precision could make a difference... I tried, but the results are the same.