# Incorrect Order of Error of Verlet Algorithm in Fortran

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods

I am trying to simulate harmonic oscillator by using Verlet Method(Original Verlet) in Fortran.
My research tells that the order of error should be 2 but my calculation showed the order of 1.

I couldn't find my mistake in my source code. What should I do?

Edit:
The algorithm I am using is below:

```
x(t+Δt) = 2x(t) - x(t-Δt) + Δt² F(t)/m

v(t) = {x(t+Δt) -x(t-Δt)}/2Δt
```

Where x(t) represents the position, v(t) represents velocity and F(t) represents Force. I recognize this is the Original Verlet  described [here](https://www.physics.drexel.edu/~valliere/PHYS305/Diff_Eq_Integrators/Verlet_Methods/Verlet/)

According to [this site](https://www.physics.drexel.edu/~valliere/PHYS305/Diff_Eq_Integrators/Verlet_Methods/Verlet/), the order of error should be at least O(Δt²) but the error of the order of my program plotted in gnuplot (below) does not have a order of O(Δt²).

[image: plot]

```
program newton_verlet

implicit none

real*16, parameter :: DT   = 3.0
real*16, parameter :: T0   = 0.0
real*16, parameter :: TEND = 2.0
integer, parameter :: NT   = int(TEND/DT + 0.5)

real*16, parameter :: M    = 1.0
real*16, parameter :: X0   = 1.0
real*16, parameter :: V0   = 0.0

real*16 x,v,t,xold,xnew,vnew,ek,ep,et,f,h
integer it,n

do n=0,20
h = DT/2**n

x = X0
v = V0

ek = 0.5*M*v*v
ep = x*x/2
et = ek + ep

xold = x - v*h

do it = 1,2**n
!   f = -x
   f = -x

   xnew = 2.0*x - xold + f*h*h/M
   v = (xnew-xold)/(2.0*h)

   ek = 0.5*M*v*v
   ep = 0.5*xnew*xnew
   et = ek + ep
   xold = x
   x = xnew

end do
write(*,*) h,abs(x-cos(DT))+abs(v+sin(DT))
end do

end program
```

Above program calculates the error of calculation for the time step h.

Comment: The Verlet method only works with all the claimed properties if the force is a function of `x`, and furthermore is the negative gradient of a potential energy function. Meaning it should be `F(x(t))`.

Comment: I am curious to know the need for `real128` (real*16) as opposed to double-precision `real64`. That alone would likely more than double the runtime of your code. Also, `real*16` is not Fortran-standard conforming. A formal way would be to `use iso_fortran_env, only: real128` and declare real variables as `real128`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Starting_the_iteration) for Verlet integrators, it seems that we need to use a more accurate way of setting the initial value of `xold` (i.e., include terms up to the force) to get the global error of order 2. Indeed, if we modify `xold` as

```
program newton_verlet
implicit none
real*16, parameter :: DT   = 3.0
real*16, parameter :: M    = 1.0
real*16, parameter :: X0   = 1.0
real*16, parameter :: V0   = 0.0

real*16 x,v,xold,xnew,f,h
integer it,n

do n = 0, 20

    h = DT / 2**n

    x = X0
    v = V0
    f = -x

    ! xold = x - v * h                     !! original
    xold = x - v * h + f * h**2 / (2 * M)  !! modified

    do it = 1, 2**n

        f = -x

        xnew = 2 * x - xold + f * h * h / M

        xold = x
        x = xnew
    end do

    write(*,*) log10( h ), log10( abs(x - cos(DT)) )
end do

end program
```

the global error becomes of order 2 (please see the log-log plot below).

[image: compare.png]

Comment: @IanBush Yes, I think you are right.. Though I tried to emphasize the key modified part (while not changing other parts), I'll add a link for OP below.

Comment: @MaoNishino As mentioned above, real*16 is not portable, so it is recommended to use the KIND mechanism; plsease see, for example, this Q/A as a starter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4 Also, please note that "1.23" etc means default real type (typically 32 bits). We can specify the kind of such a literal as 1.23_dp etc (where dp is a KIND parameter).