# Can't input value in f(x) in this Fortran code?

Tags: fortran

```
    program prob_1
    implicit real*8(a-h, o-z)
    f(x) = x**2-cos(x)
    df(x) = 2*x+sin(x)
    x0 = 0, x1 = 1
    do i = 1, 3
        if (f((x0+x1)/2) < 0)
            x0 = (x0+x1)/2
        else
            x1 = (x0+x1)/2
    end do
    print *,"x = ", x
end program
```

I'm just starting to use Fortran 90.
Now I'm using Code::blocks but I don't know exactly which line the error exists on.

I guess the problem is `f((x0+x1)/2) < 0` but don't know actually what is the real error.
what's problem is here?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran]. You should show us the exact error message you are getting. I suggest to NOT learn statement functions at the beginner stage, they are obsolete.

Comment: The `if` statement needs a `then` as well as an `endif` to get the program compiled.

Answer (score 5):

Be advised that *statement functions*, the function definitions the OP uses, are obsolescent.

> **B.3.4 Statement functions**
>
> 1. Statement functions are subject to a number of non intuitive restrictions and are a potential source of error because their syntax is easily confused with that of an assignment statement.
> 2. The internal function is a more generalized form of the statement function and completely supersedes it.
>
> **<sub>source: [F2018 Standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)</sub>**

Also the notation `REAL*8` or anything of that form has never been part of any Fortran standard (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4)):

I would suggest to rewrite the code as:

```
program prob_1
    implicit none
    double precision :: x1,x0
    integer          :: i
    x0 = 0; x1 = 1
    do i = 1, 3
        if (f((x0+x1)/2.0D0) < 0) then
            x0 = (x0+x1)/2.0D0
        else
            x1 = (x0+x1)/2.0D0
        endif
    end do
    print *,"x = ", (x0+x1)/2.0D0
contains
    function f(x)
      double precision, intent(in) :: x
      double precision             :: f
      f = x**2-cos(x)
    end function f
   function df(x)
      double precision, intent(in) :: x
      double precision             :: df
      df = 2.0D0*x+sin(x)
    end function df
end program
```

Answer (score 3):

If you change your program as follows then it will compile:

```
program prob_1
    implicit real*8(a-h, o-z)
    f(x) = x**2-cos(x)
    df(x) = 2*x+sin(x)
    x0 = 0; x1 = 1
    do i = 1, 3
        if (f((x0+x1)/2) < 0) then
            x0 = (x0+x1)/2
        else
            x1 = (x0+x1)/2
        endif
    end do
    print *,"x = ", x
end program
```

As mentionned in the comments, you have to add the semicolon `;` to separate statements in one line and you have to add the `then` as well as `endif` to your `if` condition.

Hope it helps.