# gfortran compiler Error: result of exponentiation exceeds the range of INTEGER(4)

Tags: gcc, fortran

I have this line in fortran and I'm getting the compiler error in the title. dFeV is a 1d array of reals.
`dFeV(x)=R1*5**(15) * (a**2) * EXP(-(VmigFe)/kbt)`
for the record, the variable names are inherited and not my fault. I think this is an issue with not having the memory space to compute the value on the right before I store it on the left as a real (which would have enough room), but I don't know how to allocate more space for that computation.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  `5` is an integer.  `5**(15)` is an integer raised to integer power.  (BTW, the parentheses are unneeded).  The largest default integer on your system is likely 2147483647.  5**15 = 30517578125, which is slightly larger than the largest default integer value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises as one part of your computation is done using **integer arithmetic** of type `integer(4)`.
That type has an **upper limit** of `2^31-1 = 2147483647` whereas your intermediate result `5^15 = 30517578125` is slightly larger (thanks to @evets comment).

As pointed out in your question: you save the result in a real variable.
Therefor, you could just compute that exponentiation using `real` data types: `5.0**15`.
Your formula will end up like the following

```pascal
dFeV(x)= R1 * (5.0**15) * (a**2) * exp(-(VmigFe)/kbt)
```

---

Note that `integer(4)` need not be the same implementation for every processor (thanks @IanBush).
Which just means that for some specific machines the upper limit might be different from `2^31-1 = 2147483647`.

Comment: Nitpicking - I would say "of type integer, kind 4. For most processors this kind of integer, if it is implemented, has an upper limit ..."

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comment, the value of 5**15 exceeds the range of 4-byte signed integers, which are the typical default integer type.  So you need to instruct the compiler to use a larger type for these constants.  This program example shows one method.  The ISO_FORTRAN_ENV module provides the int64 type.   UPDATE: corrected to what I meant, as pointed out in comments.

```
program test_program

use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV

implicit none

integer (int64) :: i

i = 5_int64 **15_int64

write (*, *) i

end program
```

Comment: `5_real64` rather than `5._real64` or `5_int64` would seem to be somewhat less than recommended.  But either way, I'd have thought we'd just need to have `5.**15` instead of `5**15` as it's likely the expression of the question is a real one?

Comment: 5_real64 is still an integer constant.  This answer should be deleted.

Comment: two problems here. (1) as @evets pointed out `5_real64` is still an integer. that is just misleading. (2) why would you compute the exponentiation using `real64` but save the result in an `int64` type? the whole computation should just be done using floating point values..

Answer (score 0):

Although there does seem to be an additional point here that may be specific to gfortran:

```
integer(kind = 8) :: result
result = 5**15
print *, result
```

gives: Error: Result of exponentiation at (1) exceeds the range of INTEGER(4)
while

```
integer(kind = 8) :: result
result = 5**7 * 5**8
print *, result
```

gives: 30517578125

i.e. the exponentiation function seems to have an integer(4) limit even if the variable to which the answer is being assigned has a larger capacity.

Comment: The left-hand side of intrinsic assignment never affects the evaluation of the right-hand side.

Comment: There is no exponentiation in `5*15`. Please check that your code is what you actually compiled and tested. Also, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4 to see why using just `8` in `integer(kind = 8)` is ugly and not portable.