# Fortran code executes under Intel and GNU, fails under Cray

Tags: fortran, cray

I have made this program as simple as I can:

```
module buffers
complex(8), allocatable :: iobuff(:,:)
end module buffers


program useAllocate

use buffers

integer(kind=4) :: rc=0
character(len=16) :: instr

integer(kind=8) :: abwds
integer(kind=4) :: anbs

call get_command_argument(1, instr)
read(instr,*) abwds
call get_command_argument(2, instr)
read(instr,*) anbs

call allocateBuffers(abwds, anbs, rc)

end program




SUBROUTINE allocateBuffers(arg_buff_wds, arg_num_buffs, retcode)

use buffers

IMPLICIT none

integer(kind=8), INTENT(in)  :: arg_buff_wds
integer(kind=4), INTENT(in)  :: arg_num_buffs
integer(kind=4), INTENT(out) :: retcode

print *,'allocating iobuff ', arg_buff_wds,'X',arg_num_buffs
ALLOCATE(iobuff(arg_buff_wds, arg_num_buffs), stat = retcode)
print *,'iobuff allocated'
print *,'iobuff has shape ',shape(iobuff)
DEALLOCATE(iobuff)
print *,'iobuff freed'

END SUBROUTINE allocateBuffers
```

It works just fine under an Intel or a GNU build:

```
> ./a.out 3 3
allocating iobuff                      3 X           3
iobuff allocated
iobuff has shape            3           3
iobuff freed
```

But Cray Fortran, for some reason can't handle the allocate:

```
> ./a.out 3 3
allocating iobuff  3 X 3
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Anyone have any idea why?

(NOTES: The `complex(8)` type of `iobuff` is not the problem; the code fails with the same error no matter what type I define `iobuff` to be.  Note that the various types of the variables come from the much bigger code I am really trying to understand.)

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: You seem to compile Fortran code on a various set of compilers. It is then very important to mention that `integer(kind=8)` is very bad practice. I strongly suggest you to make use of the `iso_fortran_env` module and the variables `INT32` and `INT64` therein. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3170438/8344060) for a bit more information on `kind`

Comment: @M.A   Just ftn `ab.F90`.  Just for grins I tried `ftn -I . ab.F90`.  Same result.  I use the same commands for Intel and GNU.

Comment: Try to simplify the code even further, it is still quite long. As much as possible. Delete and test, delete and test, delete and test. I uncovered several bugs in the Cray compiler when compiling my code several years ago.

Comment: If you change abwds to be an int32, and obviously also the corresponding dummy argument, what happens? Also what version of the cray compiler?

Comment: The program seems to work all right with `Cray Fortran : Version 10.0.4`.