# mpifort -DMPI compilation error: Derived type 'mpi_status' is used as an actual argument. Works with Intel Fortran, but not GNU Fortran

Tags: compiler-errors, raspberry-pi, fortran, mpi, gfortran

I'm trying to compile a Fortran program using the gfortran MPI wrapper mpifort with the -DMPI flag. I get the following error:

```
mpifort -O3 -fopenmp -DMPI -fc=gfortran-11 -fallow-argument-mismatch  -c wavefunction.F90
wavefunction.F90:486:53:

  486 |     call mpi_file_read_all(fh, neig, 1, mpi_integer, mpi_status, ierr)
      |                                                     1
Error: Derived type 'mpi_status' is used as an actual argument at (1)
```

You can find the entire Makefile (and program code) [here](https://github.com/GaffaSnobb/kshell/blob/master/src/Makefile), see the mpifort option. I've tried using gfortran versions 9, 10 and 11, all producing the same error. I have successfully compiled this very same Fortran code with -DMPI using the Intel Fortran compiler (mpiifort), but I cannot use the Intel compiler this time since I'm trying to compile on a Raspberry Pi 4 and I don't think the Intel compilers work with ARM. I've done a lot of Ducking trying to find a solution, but I have not been successful yet. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to supply a status object, not the word `mpi_status`. This program is wrong. Maybe it compiles because Fortran has no reserved words.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Victor. But how come this works with the Intel Fortran compiler? Not only does the program compile with mpiifort, but it runs just fine on hundreds of nodes on a supercomputer!

Comment: @VictorEijkhout `mpi_status` is an integer array, as can be seen in line 471 [here](https://github.com/GaffaSnobb/kshell/blob/f7154f543eee23db3546d6b86ea98355627ba788/src/wavefunction.F90#L471) and that seems to be in agreement with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-passing-interface/mpi-file-read-all-function)

Comment: Names of variables can never be in agreement with documentation. Also, your documentation uses the name `status`. I think the problem is that in newer version of the MPI-Fortran interface `MPI_Status` is a fortran "Type". Just use a different name. (I'm not 100% sure of this explanation because normally you need to `use mpi_f08` to get this interface, and you're only doing `use mpi`. Of course it maybe a good idea for you to move to the 2008 standard, so start using the `mpi_f08` module. It's much nicer.)

Comment: You really have to show the offending part of the code. The line from the error message and all relevant declarations are an absolute minimum that *sometimes* suffice, but normally a full [mcve] is in order. No, a link to an external repository is not enough.

Comment: Which MPI library (vendor and version) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. First, I removed all MPI installations and reinstalled MPI with `apt install openmpi-bin`. Earlier I used `mpich`. When compiling after this reinstall, I got another error message: `Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic 'mpi_file_read_at_all' at (1)`. The problem here was that the parameter `COUNT` to [the subroutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-passing-interface/mpi-file-read-at-all-function) was of the wrong type. In the program, it was `integer(8)`, but the subroutine expected `integer(4)`. Due to the wrong type, the compiler could not find any subroutine matching the signature, hence the error message.

I kindly thank the people in the comment section for taking time from their day to give me advice.

Comment: Please be aware that 1. MPI mostly specifies the type `integer` for the arguments, not `integer(4)` or `integer(8)`. 2. Using literal numbers like 4 or 8 in `integer(4)` is not portable and will fail with several compilers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4/24927806

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the info! I saw first that the MPI subroutines in question did not accept `integer(8)` which was explicitly stated in the program code. I then tried `integer` and it worked fine. Not knowing how many bytes `integer` defaults to, I tried `integer(n)` for a few different values `n` before finding that 4 bytes was the only one accepted. For my compiler, `integer` must then mean 4 bytes, so I specified this in my post.