# Why MPI_REDUCE shows different number at some array locations?

Tags: fortran, mpi, message-passing

```
program main_mpi_test

    use mpi
    implicit none
    integer(kind=8) :: n                  
    integer(kind=8) :: max_optical_depth  
    integer(kind=8) :: bin               
    integer(kind=8) :: tmax               
    integer(kind=8) :: sum_scatt          
    integer(kind=8) :: i,j,k
    real(kind=8)    :: rad                

    real(kind=8), dimension(:), allocatable :: send_results, recv_results
    integer :: nrank, nproc,ierr,root

    call MPI_INIT(ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nrank, ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierr)
    call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    root = 0

    max_optical_depth = 10
    bin = 10
    tmax = max_optical_depth*bin

    allocate(send_results(tmax))
    allocate(recv_results(tmax))
    
    do i = nrank+1, tmax, nproc
        rad = real(i)/real(bin)
        send_results(i) = rad
        print*,'send', rad, send_results(i)
    end do

    call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    call MPI_REDUCE(send_results, recv_results, tmax, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                    MPI_SUM, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

    if (nrank ==0) then
        do i = 1, tmax
            rad = real(i)/real(bin)
            print*,'recv',rad, recv_results(i)
        end do
    end if

    call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
    deallocate(send_results)
    deallocate(recv_results)

end program main_mpi_test
```

This is my code.
I use `MPI_REDUCE`. And I use mpiifort compiler.

And the problem is when I print recv_results,
the value of `rad` and `recv_results` must be equal, but it shows Nan or a large number about 1e186 at a some locations in the array.
In other locations, `rad` and `recv_results` have the same value.

How can I solve this problem?

[print rad, recv_results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP1RI.png)

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Please do not use pictures for results like numbers and other text output. Just copy and paste the result as text.

Comment: Be aware that using `kind=8` is not a very good practice. The values like 8 are not portable, even if it will work on most compilers. They are certainly not guaranteed to be compatible with `MPI_DOUBLE _PRECISION`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4/3170438 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: Using integer(8) is never a good idea for the reason @VladimirFГероямслава gives amongst others, and its use is probably incompatible with MPI - use default integers would be my very strong suggestion. Also you only initialise parts of your send_results array - what value do you expect the uninitialised parts to take? There's no need for it to be zero, it could be any value.

Comment: Finally you don't need the MPI_barrier, mpi_reduce is already blocking and has an implicit barrier. Rule of thumb, you *never* need an mpi_barrier except for measuring timing, debugging, and possibly when using shared memory.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Thanks for tip of How to Ask.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава And I use integer(kind=8), so When i call MPI_REDUCE I use data type MPI_INTEGER8. It works well now. And additionally i forgot about initialize the send_results(:), recv_results(:) array to 0.

Comment: @IanBush Thank you for letting me know about MPI_REDUCE already blocking. And actually i need to use integer(8), because i care about very large numbers.

Comment: @HyungJoeKwon You need some large integer kind. But specifying that using `integer(8)` is thecwrong way to do that. See those links about what kinds actually are. Beware, `MPI_INTEGER8` is for the non-standard `integer*8`, not for `integer(8)`. These do not have to be the same. You write *It works well now.*. But it is not guaranteed to always work, that is the point.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Oh i see. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has quite a lot of problems.

1. As noted in the comments use of `real(8)` and `integer(8)` is bad practice. They are not portable, may not do what you expect, and may not even be supported by a compiler. Learn about Fortran kinds from your favourite Fortran book or tutorial, and the links Vladimir provides ([Fortran: integer*4 vs integer(4) vs integer(kind=4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4/3170438) and [Fortran 90 kind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter)) are useful supporting material. My preferred way would be to use the `iso_fortran_env` standard module, see my program below
2. Whatever `integer(8)` does (if it is supported) it is unlikely to be compatible with the MPI library. MPI is defined (for most routines) in terms of default Fortran integers, so I strongly suggest you use default Fortran integers
3. You don't initialize all of the array `send_results`. Thus any results are possible as you observe. Uninitialized things can take any value, only by luck will they be zero.
4. The `Real` function with only one argument converts that argument to a value of default real kind, which is not what you want here. This is closely related to 1) above, but to get the kind you want you need to supply that kind. See my program below
5. While not a bug use of `MPI_Barrier` in the code below is completely unnecessary and just wastes times - `MPI_Reduce` is already blocking. As a rule of thumb you *never* need an mpi_barrier except for measuring timing, debugging, and possibly when using shared memory

( For the purists I should also probably call `MPI_Type_create_f90_real` but I'll be lazy and assume `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` maps to `real64` )

Anyway, here's my program, and it working with gfortran, ifort and ifx

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat red.f90
Program main_mpi_test

  Use iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64

  Use mpi
  
  Implicit None

  Real( wp ), Dimension(:), Allocatable :: send_results, recv_results

  Real( wp )    :: rad                

  Integer :: n                  
  Integer :: max_optical_depth  
  Integer :: bin               
  Integer :: tmax               
  Integer :: sum_scatt          
  Integer :: i,j,k
  Integer :: nrank, nproc, ierr, root

  Logical :: worked
  
  Call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  Call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nrank, ierr)
  Call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierr)
  Call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  root = 0
  
  max_optical_depth = 10
  bin = 10
  tmax = max_optical_depth*bin
  
  Allocate(send_results(tmax))
  Allocate(recv_results(tmax))

  send_results = 0.0_wp
  Do i = nrank+1, tmax, nproc
     rad = Real( i, Kind( rad ) ) / Real( bin, Kind( rad ) )
     send_results(i) = rad
!     Print*,'send', rad, send_results(i)
  End Do
  
  Call MPI_REDUCE(send_results, recv_results, tmax, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
       MPI_SUM, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  
  If (nrank ==0 ) Then
     worked = .true.
     Do i = 1, tmax
        rad = Real( i, Kind( rad ) ) / Real( bin, Kind( rad ) )
!        Write( *, * ) 'recv', rad, recv_results(i)
        worked = worked .And. ( Abs( rad - recv_results(i) ) < 1e-15_wp  )
     End Do
     Write( *, * ) "Worked? ", worked
  End If
  
  Deallocate(send_results)
  Deallocate(recv_results)
  
  Call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

End Program main_mpi_test
  
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpif90 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -O -g red.f90
red.f90:18:16:

   18 |   Integer :: i,j,k
      |                1
Warning: Unused variable ‘j’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
red.f90:18:18:

   18 |   Integer :: i,j,k
      |                  1
Warning: Unused variable ‘k’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
red.f90:13:14:

   13 |   Integer :: n
      |              1
Warning: Unused variable ‘n’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
red.f90:17:22:

   17 |   Integer :: sum_scatt
      |                      1
Warning: Unused variable ‘sum_scatt’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
 Worked?  T
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpiifort red.f90
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
 Worked?  T
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpiifort -fc=ifx red.f90
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
 Worked?  T
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$
```